# Function Convergence

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f,g : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ are continuous functions with $g$ strictly increasing. Show that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ we can find some constants $a_1,\ldots, a_n \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$\left| f(x) - \sum_{k = 0}^n a_k (g(x))^k \right| < \varepsilon$$
for all $x \in [a, b]$.

I haven't really made any progress besides fooling around with the fact that $g$ is bounded.

I was wondering if I could get a hint.

Thanks!

Comment: I kind of like this wording of the problem:

Suppose $f,g : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.  Then there is a polynomial p such that $|f(x) - p(g(x))| < \epsilon$ for all $x \in [a,b]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $g(a)=c$ and $g(b)=d$.  Let $g^{-1}:[c,d]\to [a,b]$ be the inverse function of $g$.  You can approximate $f\circ g^{-1}:[c,d]\to\mathbb R$ with polynomial functions using the Weierstrass approximation theorem, then compose with $g$ to get the result stated above.  (Note that you will need to give a reason why $g^{-1}$ is continuous.)